# Question about quotient group - is the operation defined or is it a consequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a normal subgroup $N \le G$.  Do we *define* the operation $*$ on $G/N$ to be

$$(aN) * (bN) = abN$$

or is the group operation the usual product,

$$aNbN = \{an_1bn_2 : n_1, n_2 \in N \}$$

with the above being $abN$ due to normality?

Comment: The first one, as the set $\,\{an_1bn_2\;:\; n_i\in N\}\,$ is NOT a left (right) coset of $\,N\,$ in $\,G\,$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Are you sure?   By normality $aNbN = abNN = abN$?

Comment: In a nutshell, $(aN) * (bN) = abN$ is a candidate for a group operation, and normality is enough to ensure that this operation is *well defined*.

Comment: It's just that the "cosets" are equivalence classes, @user56728, and in a quotient group we work with a special representative of each such class, denoted by $\,aN\,$ ,and not with the whole set $\,aN:=\{an\;;\;n\in N\}\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm saying $\{an_1bn_2 : n_i \in N\}$ is a left coset by the normality of $N$, contrary to what you just said.  I may be wrong; please correct me if I am.

Comment: @DonAntonio The equivalence class $[ab] = abN = aNbN$, so I'm confused by your statement.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. It might clear up some of the confusion in your conversation with @DonAntonio. Please comment if you still have questions and I or another use will try to answer them.

Comment: I didn't say such a thing, @user56728: read carefully. I only said that you don't need to carry the whole *set* $\,aN\,$ to work with the quotient group N, but only with *one* of its representatives...I think you may have not yet studied that left (right) cosets of a subgroup in a group are in fact equivalence classes...Of course, with $\,N\triangleleft G\,$ , it's easy to show that $\,xN=Nx\,\,,\,\forall\,x\in G\,$ , but this is unrelated to what you asked and to what I answered.

Answer (score 3):

We do have to define some sort of operation on $G/N$ to get a group structure, and so we can either write $aN\cdot bN=aNbN$, using the operation in $G$, or we can formally set $aN\cdot bN=abN$. You are right that either definition follows from the other via normality.

If we define $aN\cdot bN=aNbN$ using multiplication in $G$, then we ought to make sure that $aNbN$ is a left coset of $N$. You can check that all such products $aNbN$ will be left cosets of $N$ if and only if $N$ is normal.

If we formally define $aN\cdot bN=abN$, we should make sure that our multiplication is well-defined, which means our multiplication rule does not depend on the choice of representative. In other words, if $aN=a^\prime N$, and $bN=b^\prime N$, then we need $abN=a^\prime b^\prime N$ for our multiplication rule to be well-defined. You can check that normality is precisely the condition that makes this true.

Answer (score 2):

You can take both as a definition of $aN \cdot bN$, since
$$(aN)(bN) = a(Nb)N = a(bN)N = ab(NN) = abN$$
by normality of $N$.